# Is there a way to remove a single plot from existing axes?

Tags: matlab, plot, axes

Is there an easy way to remove a plotted line from a set of axes without clearing everything else on the axes? I'm trying to implement a GUI with a listbox containing several data sets. I can make the callback function plot the selected data, but I'm not sure how to 'unplot' it when I deselect a data set. Any ideas?

Comment: you might be interested in `clickableLegend` on FEX: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21799-clickablelegend

Comment: @Amro: Excellent suggestion! Thanks for bringing this to my attention.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you save a handle to the created graphics object, you can call [DELETE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/delete.html) on it to remove it from the plot:

```
hLine = plot(...);  %# Create a line with PLOT
delete(hLine);      %# ...and delete it
```

Alternatively, if you didn't save the handle in a variable, you can search for it using [FINDOBJ](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/findobj.html), then delete it when you find it.

If you don't actually want to *delete* it, but simply turn the visibility of the line on and off, you can set the [`'Visible'` property](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/lineseriesproperties.html#Visible) of the graphics object accordingly:

```
set(hLine,'Visible','off');  %# Make it invisible
set(hLine,'Visible','on');   %# Make it visible
```

Comment: I swear I tried this, but it didn't work then, and now it does.

Comment: Ah, I was using `delete plothandle` not `delete(plothandle)`

Comment: @Doresoom: That explains it. The command syntax `delete plothandle` would be looking for a *file* named `plothandle` to delete.

Comment: @Doresoom, `delete plothandle` is equivalent to `delete('plothandle')`

Comment: But this does not remove the legend if there is one, does it?

Comment: @RupertJones, true, but this will fix the legend: `legend('off'),legend('show')`

Comment: @Juhl: Thanks, but I meant the individual legend for the plot. I only figured out the way by hiding each individual component (text, line, ...) of the respective legend item.

Comment: @RupertJones I've switched from legend(...) towards plot(..., ,'DisplayName',{'V_x','V_y','V_z'}) which will keep annotations for each line.