# How to delete a single element in a Matlab plot

Tags: plot, matlab-figure

I have a simple plot of unsorted data, like:

```
plot(x, y, 'ko')
```

Now I have visualized some data that I would like remove. There is a way to do this directly on the plot, without searching the data in the matrix?

Thank you and bye,
Giacomo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the plots are only one-way visualizations of your code and you can't edit your data from the plots. You have to delete objects/lines [programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3388641/860196) or you can turn specific plots off (doesn't change the underlying data) with [clickableLegend](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21799-clickablelegend).

Comment: Yes, you have confirmed a my idea. Thank you.