# How to remove line plots from the image?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

There is any command or fcn in matlab to remove line or plot from the image
?

I would appreciate for any help/advice.

Comment: if you still have the handle to the plot, you can try using the `set` function to set the "XData" and "YData" to nothing.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3388664/3635260)

Comment: if its just for visualization you can use the plot browser in the view menu